# How do I make magenta in my PNG transparent in HTML5/Canvas/JS?

Tags: tiles, html-canvas, transparency

I'm putting together a simple hex map to use within an HTML5 / Canvas / JS game and before I get round to sorting any custom graphics, I was wondering if anybody knew how to make the pink/magenta backgrounds transparent so that I can overlap my tiles?

Cheers!

Comment: The pink is called Magenta. It's commonly used because it's a really bright colour and nobody actually wants to use it, so you can make all magenta in the bitmap/png transparent without harming the useful colour data. What you should really be asking is "How do I make magenta in my PNG transparent in HTML5/Canvas/JS?"

Comment: Good point. In that case, any suggestions on that front? I assumed it was part of the PNG file not part of the code?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in your environment, I would recommend editing your question.

Comment: Really, you should just edit the magenta to be transparent in any image editor that can support transparency (so, not MS Paint).  Doing the same with canvas and javascript will be slower.

Comment: Taking this example: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_9EuU9pUTGUE/TTzjwtqEWbI/AAAAAAAAAGw/PAFgZyQrMzk/s1600/solidhex_hex_text.PNG - Just seeing whether I can do what you suggest with GIMP.

Comment: @thedaian A programatic alternative is still nice, for people (like me) who generates images from their game.

Comment: @Noctrine: Extended my answer. Hope you like it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As thedaian mentioned in his comment, converting the magenta pixels to transparent in JavaScript is going to be slow. You should convert your images to a suitable format beforehand.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can be really useful for this kind of tasks. Converting your tile with magenta background to an image with transparency is as simple as this:

```
convert myOpaqueTile.png -transparent "#FF00FF" myTransparentTile.png
```

This will convert your file with magenta background (`myOpaqueTile.png`) to a file with a transparent background (will be saved as `myTransparentTile.png`).

Of course you could also use Photoshop, GIMP or something like Paint.NET for this.

---

**Update:** If you want to do the whole thing in code (JavaScript), then look into the `getImageData` function of the HTML5 canvas element. Here's an [article about canvas image manipulation](http://beej.us/blog/2010/02/html5s-canvas-part-ii-pixel-manipulation/).

And here's some sample code that will convert magenta pixels to transparent ones in JavaScript:

```js
// source file to load
var file = "testData.png";

// color to make transparent. Magenta here...
var transparentColor = {
    r : 255,
    g : 0,
    b : 255
};

var img = new Image();
img.src = file;
img.onload = function(){
    // create a source canvas. This is our pixel source
    var srcCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    srcCanvas.width = img.width;
    srcCanvas.height = img.height;

    // create a destination canvas. Here the altered image will be placed
    var dstCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    dstCanvas.width = img.width;
    dstCanvas.height = img.height;

    // append the canvas elements to the container
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(srcCanvas);
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(dstCanvas);

    // get context to work with
    var srcContext = srcCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var dstContext = dstCanvas.getContext("2d");

    // draw the loaded image on the source canvas
    srcContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // read pixels from source
    var pixels = srcContext.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    // iterate through pixel data (1 pixels consists of 4 ints in the array)
    for(var i = 0, len = pixels.data.length; i < len; i += 4){
        var r = pixels.data[i];
        var g = pixels.data[i+1];
        var b = pixels.data[i+2];

        // if the pixel matches our transparent color, set alpha to 0
        if(r == transparentColor.r && g == transparentColor.g && b == transparentColor.b){
            pixels.data[i+3] = 0;
        }
    }

    // write pixel data to destination context
    dstContext.putImageData(pixels,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Answer was spot on, thanks. I happened to use GIMP at the same time - found this resource. http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/06/17/how-to-change-background-color-to-transparent-in-gimp/